# virtualization and visual studio 2010

Tags: virtualization, visual-studio

Is it possible using windows 7 or windows server 2008 to create 5 VMWare virtual machines so that 5 developers can use them using thin clients to work with Visual Studio 2008/2010 with all components (sql server express, IIS etc). what can be the options and the hardware specs for server and clients?

I am looking forward for all opinions.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible.

That said, make sure you have enough power on the machine - CPU, RAM. VS is VPU intensive during compiles etc.

Given the price of thin desktops - it basically makes no sense, sorry ;) Mostly because if you check the price of a thin desktop (and do not forget you still need virtual machines with 6-8gb RAM).... then you saved pretty much nothing. Can be you even pay more.

Comment: Thin clients are great for standard office work.  They'll fit the needs of 90% of the workforce.  I used to work for a company that pushed it for 100% of their and their clients' workforces (as a small outsourcing company for local SMBs), and it caused nothing but pain for that 10% that it doesn't apply to.  Anyone needing to open an IDE is in the 10%.

Note: Execs, with very little exception, fall within that 90%...

Just my $0.02...

-Waldo

Comment: VDI is easier to maintain and more scalable than physical desktops; however, if these are not cost considerations then normal workstations are probably more cost effective. You'd want a minimum of 1 CPU core, 2-4GB RAM, and 1 HD Spindle per Virtual Desktop on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be possible, but I'm not sure that it would be any cheaper than 5 mid spec desktops which would get better performance if they are all being used simultaneously.  It could be an advantage if you need a particularly powerful machine and they were not using it concurrently.  Also don't forget that you would still need 5 software licences either way.